# M2Crypto load private key from X509 object

Tags: python, x509, private-key

I don't know how to load X509 private key into M2Crypto.SSL.Context.

Does it use M2Crypto.X509.X509_Store.add_X509 function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The certificate and the private key of a `Context` are set by the [`Context.load_cert()`](https://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.SSL.Context%27.Context-class.html#load_cert) or [`Context.load_cert_chain()`](https://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.SSL.Context%27.Context-class.html#load_cert_chain) methods, e.g:

```
from M2Crypto import SSL
ctx = SSL.Context()
ctx.load_cert('/path/to/certificate.pem', '/path/to/privkey.pem')
```

---

Edit: To work directly with X509 objects and private keys you need to use the low-level `M2Crypto.m2` API.

Example:

```
from M2Crypto import SSL, X509, EVP, RSA, m2
ctx = SSL.Context()
x509 = X509.load_cert('/path/to/cert.pem')

evp = EVP.PKey()
rsa = RSA.load_key('/path/to/privkey.pem')
evp.assign_rsa(rsa)

# or instantiate evp key differently, e.g. directly from file:
# evp = EVP.load_key('/path/to/privatekey.pem')

m2.ssl_ctx_use_x509(ctx.ctx, x509.x509)
m2.ssl_ctx_use_pkey_privkey(ctx.ctx, evp.pkey)

# rsa key could be used directly instead:
# m2.ssl_ctx_use_rsa_privkey(ctx.ctx, rsa.rsa)

# verify everything went ok
m2.ssl_ctx_check_privkey(ctx.ctx)
```

Comment: I mean load private key from X509 object not by from file

Comment: An X509 object doesn't have a private key, it only has the corresponding public key. To work with an X509 object you'd need to use the low-level api from `M2Crypto.m2`, e.g: `m2.ssl_ctx_use_x509(ctx.ctx, x509obj.x509)` and then set the corresponding private key using `m2.ssl_ctx_use_rsa_privatekey(ctx.ctx, key.rsa)` (or `m2.ssl_ctx_use_pkey_privatekey(ctx.ctx, key.pkey)` for other key types).

Comment: thanks you, mata. My question should be "load EVP.PKEY and X509 objects into context".

Comment: Ah, ok, then I'll update my answer with the information I posted as comment